# 100 % accuracy on training validation sets- is the model overfitting?

Tags: conv-neural-network

[image]

I have three sets of data. Training, validation and testing data. I also drew the graph of accuracy and loss.
Overfit does not appear to have occurred.
The accuracy of the test data was 98.4.
Is my model good or overfit?
[MODEL ACCURACY AND LOSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baSdj.png)

Is my CNN model overfitted?

Answer (score 0):

**You have a good model!** You can see from the loss graph that the loss on both the training and test sets is getting smaller - this means that your model learns the patterns of the training set and uses them well for the test. If overfitting were observed in your model, then the validation loss would increase over time, while the train loss would decrease.